# find y in order V not span space R^3

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces

If we have V=span(v1,v2,v3) with v1=(8,10,12), v2=(y,10,2)
and v3=(8,6,4), find y so that V don't span R^3.I  should solve it with linear equations

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1969695/find-y-so-that-textspan-8-10-12-y-10-2-8-6-4-ne-bbb-r3#comment4043412_1969695

Answer (score 3):

A hint:

These vectors are as you wish  if they are linearly dependent(why?). One possible way to do so is to build a matrix with them as columns and then find the value in which the determint of the matrix is zero. I think $y=18$.